# Table data pass into stored procedure as param and insert into another table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have this table and I need to pass each row value into a stored procedure and then it will return the list of dates for each row between `start_date` and `end_date`.

The procedure only returns two columns `interval_start`, `interval_end` but I'm trying to show the `ID` column from table `A` with the list of dates. After that, the output will insert into another table only once for each `ID`.

Table A:

```
ID  start_date  end_date
1   2016-01-01  2020-12-31
2   2017-01-01  2020-12-31
3   2018-01-01  2020-12-31
4   2019-01-01  2020-12-31
5   2020-01-01  2020-12-31
```

Stored procedure:

```
call make_intervals('2016-01-01','2020-12-31')
```

This procedure return:

```
interval_start  interval_end
2016-01-01      2016-12-31
2017-01-01      2017-12-31
2018-01-01      2018-12-31
2019-01-01      2019-12-31
2020-01-01      2020-12-31
```

And I want to get this return as below and then insert into another table:
(sample)

```
aid interval_start  interval_end
1   2016-01-01      2016-12-31
1   2017-01-01      2017-12-31
1   2018-01-01      2018-12-31
1   2019-01-01      2019-12-31
1   2020-01-01      2020-12-31
2   2016-01-01      2016-12-31
2   2017-01-01      2017-12-31
2   2018-01-01      2018-12-31
3   2019-01-01      2019-12-31
3   2020-01-01      2020-12-31
```

put this value into table B:

```
aid (int),
interval_start (date),
interval_end (date)
```

If any on of `id` insert once then this will not insert again.

Please help me to get this done.

Comment: May be your ID is primary key or Unique in Table B. For that reason, I t doesn't save duplicate value So check your ID data type

Comment: This question is confusing

Comment: is there any way to pass `table A` as param into procedure@Drew

Comment: the best way is via a set of parameters to isolate the rows in `tableA`. If you truly need various tables to go in (`tableA` , `tableB`, ...) sure you can do that, if that is really the question

Comment: Such as http://hastebin.com/sebozojiwu.sql ... note that dynamic sql like this with concats followed by `EXECUTE` will never be screaming fast. I profile it all and if it is fast enough I stick with it

Comment: In fact it is pretty ugly. I should be doing a join or a left join. But since it runs once a day from a scheduled event and takes 2 seconds, I left it alone. So don't use correlated subqueries like that as a guidepost of what to do. The point is that you can do dynamic sql if needed.

Comment: @Drew - `table A` data set could be use as start_date and end_date in the procedure either way. could u see this link please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40832502/how-to-use-a-set-of-data-to-generate-date-list-between-two-date-for-each-id-in-m